# How to get resources by absolute path without subdirectory when the app is deployed to subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, webpack, src

We deployed the app to a subdirectory on our web server (subdirectory name depends on region, e.g. `/france`).
The questions is how to get resources by absolute path without adding subdirectory name to the path. For example to get image  I'd like to write 
`<img src='/Images/logo.png' />` not `<img src='/france/Images/logo.png' />`

If I write src='Images/logo.png' (without the first slash), it works for the first level urls like `domain-name/france/competitions` but doesn't work for more complex URLs like `domain-name/france/competition/123` because request will be `domain-name/france/**competitions**/Images/logo.png` what is not correct

I tried to use webpack alias but it doesn't work (maybe I've made mistake):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      Images: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/Images')
    } 
}
```

Comment: hey, try to use resolve.alias:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias

Comment: hi @VasylGutnyk I've tries it, it is described in the question body